# I want to show only four records taken from my Jtable

Tags: java, swing

My JTable works fine and currently shows me all the usernames in my table but what I require is to show **only the first four records**.

This is the code I have used

```
private void fillTableUserList(){
    try{
        String sql = "Select username from user order by date_joined desc";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
        latestTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your sql-query to return max 4 values with the SQL keyword

LIMIT : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Basically your sql string would be

```
String sql = "Select username from user order by date_joined desc LIMIT 4";
```